# create nodes programatically with gmf but without setting its properties

Tags: eclipse-emf-ecore, eclipse-gmf

I want to create nodes programatically with its properties but using the folowing codes nodes can be created but its properties can not be set.

```js
     CreateUnspecifiedTypeRequest request_ch = new
             CreateUnspecifiedTypeRequest(
                 Collections.singletonList(xxxElementTypes.yy),
                 diagramEditPart.getDiagramPreferencesHint());
     Command command = diagramEditPart.getCommand(request);
     command.execute();
```

```
    then element.set("idof element")    but the properties of the node still empty.
```

may someone help me .thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this method in order to create nodes programatically. The node and the properties appear just fine and you can edit them. (note that there is also a way to edit the properties programmatically, with another type of command (EMF))

```
public void createAndExecuteShapeRequestCommand(IElementType type, EditPart parent) {
    CreateViewRequest actionRequest = CreateViewRequestFactory
            .getCreateShapeRequest(
                    type,
                    PreferencesHint.USE_DEFAULTS);
    org.eclipse.gef.commands.Command command = parent.getCommand(actionRequest);
    command.execute();
}
```

---

A sample caller of that method if the node is meant to be added in the main area of the diagram.

```
createAndExecuteShapeRequestCommand(xxx.diagram.providers.xxxElementTypes.ELEMENT_HERE, diagramEditPart);
```

---

A sample caller of that method if the node is meant to be added inside another node or compartment.

```
DiagramEditPart diagramEditPart = getDiagramEditPart(); //diagram.getDiagramEditPart();

"ParentElement" parentElement = (("Root_ELEMENT") diagramEditPart.resolveSemanticElement())."getTheElement"();
List list = getDiagramGraphicalViewer().findEditPartsForElement(EMFCoreUtil.
                    getProxyID(parentElement),
                    TheElementsEDITPART.class);

createAndExecuteShapeRequestCommand(xxx.diagram.providers.xxxElementTypes.ELEMENT_HERE, (EditPart)list.get(0));
```

Note that, if you wish to call this method from other class than the one of the xxxDiagramEditor.java you will need somehow to pass there the diagramEditPart.